# How to do an inline IF array constructor in Chapel?

Tags: list-comprehension, chapel

I'd like to create a subset of a domain based on a conditional.  I could do a loop, but I'm looking to see if I can use an inline if.

Just re-creating the array `d` looks like

```
var d = {1..8};
var e =  [0.875, 0.625, 0.625, 1.0, 0.625, 0.875, 0.625, 0.625];
var p = 0.7;

var vs = for i in d do i;
writeln(" vs: ", vs);
```

However, I want to extract the `d` where `e[d] < p` into `vs`.  Is there an approach like?

```
vs = [i in d where e[i] < p]
writeln(vs);  // {2,3,5,7,8}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the desired result:

```
var vs = for i in d do
           if e[i] < p then i;
```

Note that `vs` is an array and not a domain. If you want a domain that you can use, you should use an associative domain:

```
var vs : domain(int) = for i in d do
                         if e[i] < p then i;
```

This example will turn into something like this:

```
var vs : domain(int);
for i in d {
  if e[i] < p then
    vs.add(i);
}
```

Comment: A lovely piece, Ben. **What are the actual costs of such an "embedded iterator"** to be expected to get accrued in order to process an associative domain for about a 10TB dataset ( 64bit IEEE values ) on a single locale ( localhost ) v/s loaded onto an 8-node distributed-processing cluster?

Comment: Just added an example clarifying that the 'embedded iterator' turns into a serial loop that adds indices to the associative domain. An associative domain is very similar to a 'set' in other languages, which hopefully gives you a good idea of the cost of adding indices. This could be made faster by turning off parallel safety: var vs : domain(int, parSafe=false);